# Custom Configuration Handler Exception

Tags: vb.net, web-config

I am trying to create a custom configuration section in the web.config using the information on the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms228056.aspx

Here is the code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Dim config As Hashtable = DirectCast(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myCustomGroup/myCustomSection"), Hashtable)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Here is the web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Other configuration settings, like <system.web> -->
        <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="myCustomGroup">
                <section name="myCustomSection" type="MyConfigSectionHandler.MyHandler, MyCustomConfigurationHandler"/>
            </sectionGroup>
            <!-- Other <section> and <sectionGroup> elements. -->
        </configSections>

      <!-- Configuration section settings area. -->
      <myCustomGroup>
        <myCustomSection myAttrib1="Clowns">
          <myChildSection
              myChildAttrib1="Zippy"
              myChildAttrib2="Michael Zawondy "/>
        </myCustomSection>
      </myCustomGroup>
</configuration>
```

MyHandler.vb can be found on the webpage so I won't paste the code here.  I am faced with an exception: `{"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for myCustomGroup/myCustomSection: Could not load type 'MyConfigSectionHandler.MyHandler' from assembly 'MyCustomConfigurationHandler'. (C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\WebSite3\web.config line 13)"}`

There are similar questions online (for example here: http://csd.codeplex.com/discussions/234031) and the answerer s suggest that the assembly name is not specified in the Section Group Type element, but in my case it is.  Why am I seeing this exception? MyCustomConfigurationHandler.dll is in the bin folder of the website.

Comment: What is the root namespace for your project?

Comment: @Steven Doggart, the root namespace of the DLL is: MyCustomConfigurationHandler.

Comment: Have you tried adding the version, culture, and public token, as in the example on the MSDN that you cited?

Comment: @Steven Doggart, yes I removed one element at a time when troubleshooting.  I probably should readd them.